# Window resizing problem to detect anchor point

Tags: jquery, scroll, resize, anchor, detect

On my HTML page I have multiple sections creating a vertical scroll effect. Each one of these sections has the width and height of 100% of the screen window. At the top of the page I also have a menu set to `position: fixed`. The text color of the menu changes when the fixed menu reaches and detects an anchor point by scrolling the page.

My problem is when I resize the browser window, I loose the detection of the anchor point. So when the menu scrolls hover the anchor the menu color doesn't change.

```html
<header id="masthead" class="site-header"> Menu text </header>

<section id="section-1" class="hero"> Section 1 </section>
<section id="section-2" class="hero"> Section 2 </section>

<div class="anchor switch-menu-color"></div>

<section id="section-3" class="hero"> Section 3 </section>
<section id="section-4" class="hero"> Section 4 </section>
```

```js
var anchor = $('.switch-menu-color').offset().top - 40,
  $window = $(window);

$window.on('load scroll resize', function() {
  if ($window.scrollTop() >= anchor) {
    $("#masthead").addClass("black-text");
  } else {
    $("#masthead").removeClass("black-text");
  }
});
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because you only ever read the `offset()` of the `.switch-menu-color` element when the page loads. You also need to do that when the page is resized, like this:

```
var anchor = $('.switch-menu-color').offset().top - 40,
  $window = $(window);

$window.on({
  'load scroll': setLinkColour,
  'resize': function() {
    anchor = $('.switch-menu-color').offset().top - 40;
    setLinkColour();
  }
});

function setLinkColour() {
  $('#masthead').toggleClass('black-text', $window.scrollTop() >= anchor);
}
```

Note that I separated the `load scroll` and `resize` events for performance reasons. There's no need to re-calculate the `offset()` when the page is scrolled, only on resize.

Also note the use of `toggleClass()` with a boolean argument to make the code a little more succinct.

Comment: Thanks Rory for your answer, I do understand the code you wrote. However it's still making the same issue. When I resize the window, the anchor keeps the same position when the page loaded.